# error npm build vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hola estoy haciendo un empaquetado con vue, npm run build, y me sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR in static/js/vendor.da3768580921576be21c.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc ()) [./node_modules/vue-json-excel/dist/vue-json-excel.esm.js:222,0][static/js/vendor.da3768580921576be21c.js:586,16]

  Build failed with errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pruebauetify@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pruebauetify@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

estoy comenzando y no tengo la minima idea de como solucionarlo, no puedo actualizar versiones de vuejs y otras cosas por el servidor, disculpen en mi local funcionaba bien y al hacer el empaquetado me sale el error anterior, gracias

Comment: Aquí podría encontrar su solución:   [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975417/error-in-webpack-during-build-but-not-dev-error-in-static-from-uglifyjs

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo pero no me sirvió, sigue saliendo el error...